# MySQL query entire table using 1 of 2 given matching parameters in first query

Tags: mysql

I have three columns in a table as below:

```
+----------+---------+-----+
| forename | surname | ref |
+----------+---------+-----+
| John     | Smith   | 123 |
| Brenda   | Smith   | 123 |
| Paul     | Johnson | 123 |
| Greg     | Smith   | 222 |
| Suzanne  | Smith   | 222 |
| Allan    | Taylor  | 168 |
+----------+---------+-----+
```

The user of the website will enter their information to query against this table to see if it exists.

The query for this so far is...

```
"SELECT * FROM invites WHERE surname='$surname' AND ref='$ref'";
```

...where $surname and $ref are the submitted form values from the webpage I'm designing.

However, I want the results list on this page to show not only records exactly matching both fields, but also any forename and surname in the table that matches the ref supplied in the web form, given that the surname submitted at the same time as the ref in the form is an exact match. What would be the most efficient way to write a query for this?

Comment: You don't want the first name to be an exact match? Can you clarify what you mean by that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the query to return the result below, given surname 'Smith' and ref '123'

```
| forename | surname | ref |
----------------------------
| John     | Smith   | 123 |
| Brenda   | Smith   | 123 |
| Paul     | Johnson | 123 |
----------------------------
```

If that is the case, the query would be this:

```
select * from invites where surname = '$surname' and ref = '$ref'
union
select * from invites where ref = '$ref' and exists (select surname
from invites where surname = '$surname')
```

Comment: Thanks @Julia that's exactly what I was looking to achieve.